# Should complex silverlight pages be split into controls even if they won't be reused

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

### Background

I'm working on a silverlight page that has grown quite complex.  Its 650 lines, contains   It has four grid views, a tab control, etc.  Also note we're following the MVVM pattern.  This is silverlight 5, if that matters.

The page seems suitable to be split into a main page with four controls.  I doubt the controls would ever be reused in other pages.

One benefit is that with all of the indenting, it is a bit awkward to work with the xaml.  Second benefit is my belief that it would be easier to follow/understand if the controls were split apart.

### Questions

If I split the xaml into seperate controls, should I also split up the ViewModel?  For the same reasons, it would make the view model less complex and easier to understand in the context of just the control it works with.

Are there any potential problems with splitting the controls?  Perhaps binding issue if for some reason a checkbox on one control should affect the behavior of a different control?  But this might be solved by having the various view models have a reference to each other?

Answer (score 2):

I would say that yes you should split the page up into seperate controls and yes you should split up the viewmodel **if** the cost of doing so will be less than the cost of the maintenance difficulty created by the current model.

Most of the challenges that this presents can be addressed by having a main viewmodel that contains references to all of the child viewmodels and manages the relationships between them.